# Use form_for in Sinatra

Tags: sinatra

Can any one please help how to use form_form in Sinatra views.

I have included active support in my gemfile and have also required that in my app.rb

```
gem 'activesupport', require: 'active_support/all'
require 'active_support/all'
```

While trying to use form_for i am getting syntax errors from sinatra.

Comment: `form_for` isn’t part of Active Support, it is part of Action View. I don’t know if it can be used independently from the rest of Rails. You might want to have a look at [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/) which is based on Sinatra and has its own `form_for`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice to just do the form by hand? The freedom from railsish things!

Comment: @froderik I did it by hand. Was just a question if i want to do. I like Padrino as suggested by matt.